# Cannot install graphics tablet ; CD Drive broken and Driver not found online

Tags: installation, drivers, tablet, wacom

Okay, so I purchased a Medion USB Graphics Pad
(P82019 MD86935). I cannot install the driver software because my CD Drive is broken and no longer runs discs which is essential because what I need to is Configure Input Devices and change the settings of the tablet pen to run the program GIMP.

I've gone onto www.medion.com where you can install the drivers off the site. However my product that I purchased is *not listed on it*.

So I cannot install the driver software without having to buy a new computer that has a working disc drive or getting my disc drive fixed.

All that I need to do is to adjust my graphics tablet pen *Pressure Settings* but cannot do that without installing the drives required!

Is there any other possible way!?

Comment: You can get an external USB drive, which can run on a USB port or two. This should work fine with the disc. For help, run through the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TabletSetupWizardpen) and [help](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2140079). Also, what does `xinput list` output when you run it in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Although that's not really an Ubuntu Q, and so has little room in AskUbuntu, I'll try...
Seems to me that what you need to do is get the CD to another computer and create an ISO file from it.
You can do that using MagicIso or any other program you find fit.
Once you've done it you can bring that file to your computer and mount it, thus having your cd with all it's files on your Ubuntu.